# How to print out URL when @RequestParam throws MissingServletRequestParameterException

Tags: java, spring, url

This is a spring project. I used the codes below to handle incoming http GET request, and it's in format http://xxx.comm/vastTracking?rtbProvider=AAA&adGroupKey=BBB&transactionId=CCC&event=DDD .
When the server is running, most requests are handled correctly, but some throw exceptions - mostly are

```
unhandled exception
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required VastEventType parameter 'event' is not present.
```

In few chances they are "String cannot be converted to type VastEventType", or "parameter adGroupKey is not presented".

It looks like the incoming requests have URL trimmed sometimes. The request URL is provided by my system so it shouldn't be missing, though it sent by user's video player.
I want to know how this happens, so I want a way to print out the URL when the exception is thrown. So far I just found ways to print out all incoming URLs.

My codes:

```
@Controller
public class VastEventTrackingController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/vastTracking")
  public ResponseEntity<String> vastEventTrack( @RequestParam("rtbProvider") String strRtbProvider,
                                                @RequestParam("adGroupKey") String strAdGroupKey,
                                                @RequestParam("transactionId") String strTransactionId,
                                                @RequestParam("event") VastEventType event,
                                                HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
  }
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default all request params are `required`. See spring [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html). If you want to make them optional you should set `required=false`.

```
@RequestParam(value = "event",required = false) VastEventType event
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this parameter is mandatory. The request URL is provided by my system so it shouldn't be missing.

Comment: yes but you are passing `String` and expecting `VastEventType` i didn't understand that

Comment: VastEventType is an enum and is able to convert from a String. My trouble is this String parameter is missing, so I want to look at the whole URL string to see what happened.